# Installing Zoo for R seems to be successful, but gives `Error object 'zoo' not found

Tags: r, zoo

I don't seem to be able to install the `zoo` library. I've installed ggplot2, xts, and a lot of other libraries. Zoo is the first one to throw an error.

How can the following happen?

```
> install.packages("zoo")
trying URL 'http://cran.mirrors.hoobly.com/bin/macosx/mavericks/contrib/3.1/zoo_1.7-11.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 868268 bytes (847 Kb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 847 Kb


The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/7q/9z1s0pvd50qf30y7swrlpt_r0000gn/T//RtmpGPYn7C/downloaded_packages
> zoo
Error: object 'zoo' not found
>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Still being a noob to R. After installation, you have to remember to import the library into your environment.

```
# Install a library.
install.packages("zoo")

# Import it it into your script. 
library(zoo)
```